# Inserting some colored line in TextArea JavaFX

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, textarea

I need to insert some text line with red color in TextArea to print some statistics.

How can I proceed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the available styled-text controls - see https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/wiki/JavaFX-Controls-for-Code-Editing for a list of available ones or create a viewer based upon ListView yourself

Comment: What do you mean by a viewer based upon ListView? Can you give me an example? 
And for the first solution I work with java7